# issue with dispather servlet (Context initialization failed)

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have implemented JWT in spring web project (not spring boot)by following this tutorial [Spring Boot Security + JWT](https://medium.com/swlh/spring-boot-security-jwt-hello-world-example-b479e457664c).
I have updated spring security mvn dependency version to 5.0 which resolves many dependencies.
But now i face this error says:

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<NONE>]
```

But my application context is already configured in `web.xml`.
I have search this error and by following answers, I tried adding following code but in vain.

```
<context-param>-->
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>-->
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I am attaching web.xml, appliactionContext.xml and pom.xml file as well. I am not much aware of rules and format to ask a question here so sorry in advance if I missed anything or done things wrong.
Thanks in advance!!

[1- project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WZy6.png)
2- web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>I8FMERP - I8 Fleet Management ERP</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>i8fmerp</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <!-- Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      com.inov8.i8FMERP.security.SessionFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

3- applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

  <bean id="applicationProperties" class="com.inov8.i8FMERP.config.PropertyReader">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:mail.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>

    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <context:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.inov8.i8FMERP" />
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="i8FMERP_TransactionManager" />

  <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />

  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

  <bean id="I8FMERP_SqlServerDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:sqlserver://${i8FMERP.sqldb.server};instanceName=${i8FMERP.sqldb.instance};databaseName=${i8FMERP.sqldb.database};portNumber=${i8FMERP.sqldb.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${i8FMERP.sqldb.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${i8FMERP.sqldb.password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="60" />
    <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="240" />
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="20" />
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="5" />
    <property name="partitionCount" value="5" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="lazyInit" value="true" />


    <property name="initSQL" value="SELECT 1"></property>
    <property name="logStatementsEnabled" value="false"></property>
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="1000" />
    <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="false"></property>
    <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="READ_COMMITTED"></property>

    <property name="queryExecuteTimeLimitInMs" value="10000"></property>
    <property name="connectionTimeoutInMs" value="10000"></property>
    <property name="poolAvailabilityThreshold" value="10"></property>

    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="10"></property>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelayInMs" value="60000"></property>
    <property name="transactionRecoveryEnabled" value="true"></property>

  </bean>
  <bean id="SendMailProperty" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" />

  <bean id="I8FMERP_SqlServerJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="I8FMERP_SqlServerDataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="i8FMERP_TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="I8FMERP_SqlServerDataSource" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
  </bean>
  <task:annotation-driven />
  <bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageCron" class="com.inov8.i8FMERP.service.DemoServiceBasicUsageCron"></bean>

</beans>
```

4- pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.inov8</groupId>
    <artifactId>i8FMERP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>i8FMERP Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cryptix</groupId>
            <artifactId>cryptix</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.org.simonsite</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-rolling-appender</artifactId>
            <version>20140925-0909</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>i8FMERP</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You should have a `contextConfigLocation` for the `ContextLoaderListener` as well, you now only have it for the servlet. Next to that you are loading your application twice, which will lead to nice exceptions, weird issues later on and your dependencies are a mess as well you are mixing at least modules from 3 versions of Spring 5.3, 5.0 and 4.1 which is going to bite you as well (and I believe the Spring Security one is pulling in 5.2 as well).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your setup

1. You have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` loading the same configuration, which effectively leads to loading your whole application twice. Which in the future will lead to some nice to debug and weird issues! Not to mention you are taking up twice the memory.
2. Your dependencies are a mess you are at least mixing 3 versions of Spring (5.3, 5.0 and 4.1) this is going to bite you in the not so distant future
3. You have 2 times the `mvc:annotation-driven` tag in your configuration where only a single one should suffice.

Regarding 1 you should split your configuration in one for the `ContextLoaderListener` and one for the `DispatcherServlet`. Where the `ContextLoaderListener` one should load everything but web related beans and the `DispatcherServlet` one only web related beans.

I would also suggest sticking with the default and moving the `applicationContext.xml` to the `WEB-INF` directory and to create another file in there named `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

The `applicationContext.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

  <bean id="applicationProperties" class="com.inov8.i8FMERP.config.PropertyReader">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:mail.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Load everything BUT controllers -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.inov8.i8FMERP">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" value="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller` />
  </context:component-scan>

  <task:annotation-driven />
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="i8FMERP_TransactionManager" />
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

  <bean id="I8FMERP_SqlServerDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:sqlserver://${i8FMERP.sqldb.server};instanceName=${i8FMERP.sqldb.instance};databaseName=${i8FMERP.sqldb.database};portNumber=${i8FMERP.sqldb.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${i8FMERP.sqldb.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${i8FMERP.sqldb.password}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="60" />
    <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="240" />
    <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="20" />
    <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="5" />
    <property name="partitionCount" value="5" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="lazyInit" value="true" />


    <property name="initSQL" value="SELECT 1"></property>
    <property name="logStatementsEnabled" value="false"></property>
    <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="1000" />
    <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="false"></property>
    <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation" value="READ_COMMITTED"></property>

    <property name="queryExecuteTimeLimitInMs" value="10000"></property>
    <property name="connectionTimeoutInMs" value="10000"></property>
    <property name="poolAvailabilityThreshold" value="10"></property>

    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="10"></property>
    <property name="acquireRetryDelayInMs" value="60000"></property>
    <property name="transactionRecoveryEnabled" value="true"></property>

  </bean>
  <bean id="SendMailProperty" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" />

  <bean id="I8FMERP_SqlServerJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="I8FMERP_SqlServerDataSource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="i8FMERP_TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="I8FMERP_SqlServerDataSource" />
  </bean>
 
  <bean id="demoServiceBasicUsageCron" class="com.inov8.i8FMERP.service.DemoServiceBasicUsageCron"></bean>

</beans>
```

Then the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


  <context:component-scan base-package="com.inov8.i8FMERP" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" value="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
  </context:component-scan>

  <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />

  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
  </bean>


</beans>
```

In your `web.xml` you can now remove the `contextConfigLocation` as it now simply uses the defaults.

**NOTE:** This also removes the excessive duplicated/unnecessary tags from the XML

Regarding your dependency, or rather `pom.xml`, mess use a single version for the dependencies don't mix as that will lead to issues. You are at least mixing different version for Spring, Jackson and Javax.mail. The below should relieve some of the issues with the pom.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.inov8</groupId>
    <artifactId>i8FMERP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>i8FMERP Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- Framework versions -->
        <spring.version>5.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.3.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <javax-mail.version>1.6.0</javax-mail.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cryptix</groupId>
            <artifactId>cryptix</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.org.simonsite</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-rolling-appender</artifactId>
            <version>20140925-0909</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring31</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>i8FMERP</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**NOTES**

1. Still there is BoneCP and HikariCP, why 2 connection pools if you only use 1?
2. You defined the Java version to 1.7 through properties but your compiler is configured for 1.8?
3. You are mixing Jackson 1 and Jackson 2, that doesn't look proper
4. Commons HTTP 3.5 and 4.3?
5. XMLRPC 3.1.2 and 3.1.3, don't mix versions
6. You shouldn't need the `commons-logging` dependency as Spring already wraps that in `spring-jcl` which is included automatically